# Set function result to variable within same function on external javascript file

Tags: javascript, html

The following is not bringing the results of my function into a variable and into my html page... why?

EXTERNAL JAVASCRIPT

```
function damageRoll(min, max) {
  'use strict';

  document.getElementById("combatResult").innerHTML = damageFinal;

  min = min || peacemaker.damageMin;
  max = max || peacemaker.damageMax;

  var damageFinal = damageRoll();

  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) ) + min;}
```

HTML

```
<div id="combatResult"></div>

<button onclick="damageRoll()">Fight</button>
```

**EDIT**
Going to read through everyone's answers but min/max probably not the issue. I failed to show they get their values from another external js file and are functioning as expected in other areas of my code. Thanks.

EXTERNAL JAVASCRIPT #2

```
var peacemaker = {
damageMin: 3,
damageMax: 5,
```

};

Comment: What error is reported in the console of ou browser?  You call `damageRoll` with in `damageRoll` over an over again, creating an engless recursion. Why do you call `damageRoll`, what you xpect ath this should do?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular how to ask. Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: Let's start from the root of the issues.  The function damageRoll require 2 parameters. You are NOT providing any.

Comment: @Padmanabhan  parameters in js are always optional. You can always pass more or less paramerers then specified in the signature. And a construct like `min = min || peacemaker.damageMin` could be used to default to `peacemaker.damageMin` if no `min` was provided.

Comment: Please see edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want thing like this.

```
function damageRoll(min, max) {
  'use strict';

  min = min || peacemaker.damageMin;
  max = max || peacemaker.damageMax;

  var damageFinal = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) ) + min;
  document.getElementById("combatResult").innerHTML = damageFinal;
}
```

First, the min and max modification should be put at the front of the function. You should also consider put the `damageFinal` variable declaration earlier in the function like the above example. Don't overuse JavaScript's variable hoisting feature.

Next, your original code results in a endless self invoking. I don't understand your intention, but it will be better not to use self invoking in your situation.

PS: You can make code even simpler by using es6

```
function damageRoll(min = peacemaker.damageMin, max = peacemaker.damageMax) {

  var damageFinal = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) ) + min;
  document.getElementById("combatResult").innerHTML = damageFinal;


}
```

Comment: I most probably do. Nailed it thanks. Kudos for the trim job as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your `damageRoll()` calls do not actually contain the required parameters `min` and `max`. You must add items when you're calling it, like here:

`<button onclick="damageRoll(min, max)">Fight</button>`

and within the function itself:

```
var damageFinal = damageRoll(min, max);
```

2. You're recursively calling the function, without a base. Nothing is going to occur, because the function will never finish being called. You may want to look into this.

Comment: He has set a fallback value in his function

Comment: Where? He calls the function within the function, and doesn't check if anything has happened

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are a beginner learner so i will explain what i did instead of just posting the right answer.

First of all, you should split your function to one that handle the click event and one the calculate the result. it's better that the second function will use inner cope only (don't use variable from outside the function)

so your code should look like:

```
// example values for object
        const peacemaker = {
            damageMin: 100,
            damageMax: 100
        }

        function damageRollEvent(e) {
            'use strict';
            e.preventDefault();

            var _peacemaker = {
                min: min || peacemaker.damageMin,
                max: max || peacemaker.damageMax
            }

            var damageFinal = damageRoll(_peacemaker);
            document.getElementById("combatResult").innerHTML = damageFinal;
        }

        function damageRoll(_peacemaker) {
            'use strict';
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * (_peacemaker.max - _peacemaker.min + 1)) + _peacemaker.min;
        }
```

`damageRollEvent` function handle the event and messing with the html.

`damageRoll` returns the value you expect for and doing pure programming work.

the html

```
<div id="combatResult"></div>

    <button onclick="damageRollEvent($event)">Fight</button>
```

i didn't test the code but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way you shall proceed without recursively calling the function, you shall add a helper function in the middle. From the HTML you shall call the helper. Anyway you have to find a way to resolve the 2 variablrs, min and max. See this..

```
    function damageRoll(min, max) {

      var damageFinal = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) ) + min;

      document.getElementById("combatResult").innerHTML = damageFinal;

    }

    function throwMinMax(){

       // You should Find a way to resolve the two variables below
       // we have No idea where the peacemaker stuff come from

      var min = peacemaker.damageMin;
      var max = peacemaker.damageMax;

      damageRoll(min,max);

   }
```